# How to publish programmatically manipulated (e.g. instrumented) jars in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a multi-project build. Sub-project CoolApp depends on sub-project CrazyJar. Project CrazyJar has no sources: it uses a tool to perform byte code manipulation on an existing jar derived from non-Gradle project BigProject and wishes to publish the resulting manipulated jar to be depended on by CoolApp. It needs to publish this as a local Maven package.

Since it seems the "maven-publishing" plugin only supports "java" and "web" projects, I apply the "java" plugin to CrazyJar. But CrazyJar has no sources! I end up publishing an empty artifact. Is there any way I can mangle this to work as though it were a normal Java project? If not, anything else I might do?

Comment: The `maven-publishing` plugin (for now) only supports `java` and `web` *components*, but it alternatively allows to publish arbitrary *artifacts* (as documented in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, yeah, I misunderstood my problem slightly. Well, here was my solution anyway (based mostly off documentation for the "maven-publish" plugin):

#### Root project

```
subprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "${rootDir}/repo"
    }
  }
}
```

#### CrazyJar project

```
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

...

task createCrazyJar(type: Exec) {
  ...
}

publish {
  dependsOn "createCrazyJar"
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact createCrazyJar.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url project.repositories.maven.url
    }
  }
}
```

#### CoolApp project

```
dependencies {
  compile group: "coolproject", name: "crazyjar", version: project("CrazyJar").version
}
```